Why does updating to psycopg 3.x cause database timeouts?
I have a Django 5.x app. I've been using psycopg2, and I'm now trying to update to psycopg 3. This is pretty simple: I uninstalled everything to do with psycopg2 and installed psycopg[binary].
However, when I run my test suite now (in parallel), I am suddenly getting connection timeout expired errors that I wasn't getting before!
My database configuration is pretty straightforward:
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql",
        "NAME": get_from_env("DB_NAME", "my-db"),
        "USER": get_from_env("DB_USERNAME", "my-db-user"),
        "PASSWORD": get_from_env("DB_PASSWORD", DEFAULT_DB_PASSWORD),
        "HOST": get_from_env("DB_HOSTNAME", "localhost"),
        "PORT": get_from_env("DB_PORT", "5432"),
        "OPTIONS": {
            "connect_timeout": 3,
            "options": f"-c statement_timeout=30000ms",
        }
    },
}

The problem is with the connect_timeout: if I remove it, then things seem to work.
Does psycopg 3 change how connections work? Why would updating to 3.x cause more connection timeouts?

here they have initialised it diffirently have a look- https://github.com/dvarrazzo/django-psycopg3-backend/blob/main/configs/test_psycopg3.py

@Yuvraj ah yes this is using the built-in psycopg 3 support in django! https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/ref/databases/#postgresql-notes

This appears to be due to a bug in psycopg 3.2. By using psycopg 3.1, things work as expected. There is a GitHub issue for the bug here: https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg/issues/888
